# No puedo crear un proyecto en Laravel usando laragon

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

```
C:\laragon\www
λ laravel new app
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for mockery/mockery 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by mockery/mockery[1.4.0].
- mockery/mockery 1.4.0 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

que puedo hacer para solucionarlo 
espero su respuesta pronto Gracias

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ laravel new app para crear un proyecto.

Comment: Mmm.. Es raro porque la última versión de Laravel usa [mockery 1.3.1](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5639581ea56ecd556cdf6e6edc37ce5795740fd7/composer.json#L21). Puedes probar con `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app` en caso de que sea un problema del instalador de laravel.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ creo que ya tengo la solución solo quiero hacer unas pruebas y luego lo publico aquí.

Comment: Esta raro, pero creo que esta podría ser la solución (https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version-php-7-4-updated) ahora intente cambia manual la versión de PHP

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ pero me funciono eso y me fue perfectamente subir la versión de php de igual manera yo intente de muchas formas y no entiendo por que siempre me daba ese error pero ya lo tengo solucionado de igual manera dejare aquí el problema resulto por si alguien algún dia le pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Claro, publica cómo lo solucionaste, así le puede servir a otros. A lo que iba es a que yo no lo pude reproducir, nada más.

Comment: (https://youtu.be/Zm1EwwmHzvE) la solución aquí